# Passing Collectd Data to Statsd Running in Docker Container

Tags: docker, aggregation, statsd, collectd

I have a docker container (from here: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/hopsoft/graphite-statsd/) that has both statsd and graphite running inside of it. I then have collectd running locally on my machine, and I need help passing the data collected by collectd to statsd running inside of the docker container for the purpose of data aggregation. Can't figure out how to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

If your ran the container with `-p 8125:8125/udp` your can just run:

```
# On linux
echo "foo:1|c" | nc -u -w0 localhost 8125

# On OSX
echo "foo:1|c" | nc -u -w0 $(boot2docker ip) 8125
```

Comment: So, would that be the way to pass the data collected by collectd to the docker container instance of statsd to be used for the aggregation I'm looking for? I am really new to this kind of thing, so I apologize for my questioning, but I'm just trying to make sure I've got this straight... Like I understand that I can send a "dummy" metric like this, but how would I pass off ALL the information? Like CPU stats, memory stats, storage, etc.

Comment: Unless you need statsd summarization you could send data directly to graphite as well.

Comment: I don't know how to use the statsd plugin. I can't figure out how to find the collectd output let alone how to re-route it. That's my problem. I know that collectd is working though because I can see the proof of it on the collectd-web front end, but my boss wants to use statsd, so I am trying to send the data collected by collectd to statsd to have it aggregated to his liking, but I am having trouble re-routing that. Do you understand what I mean because I feel like I am saying it badly.